# C++ const static member array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, static, constants

I have class Foo with a member variable bar which is a very big array of dynamic_bitset. I would like to make variable bar static for the sake of memory, I would also like it to be const. The value of bar is stored in a predefined file. Where should I put the code for reading the file and initializing bar?

Comment: What's the actual type of the object?

Comment: Don't describe code, show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MadScienceDreams's solution will probably work, but you can do this much more simply:

## In header

```
class A
{
     static const vector<dynamic_bitset> s;
public:
     // ...
};
```

## In implementation file

```
vector<dynamic_bitset> LoadBitsets()
{
    //...
    return something;
}

const vector<dynamic_bitset> A::s(LoadBitsets());
```

The move constructor should get used automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also declared LoadBitsets() as static in header file.

Comment: @nullgraph: I can't see any reason for `LoadBitsets` to be in the header file at all.  Is it accessing private static members of the class?

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to access the file name which is a private static const string of the class. I have another function in the class that writes these bitset to the file, this is a one time operation, so I want to make sure they have the same file name.

Comment: @nullgraph: Sounds like something that could be a file-global static variable inside the initialization file.  (Most `static private` constants should be hidden away in the initialization file and not appear in the header file at all)

Comment: Can you paraphrase on why static private constants should not be in header file?

Comment: @nullgraph: It's just better encapsulation.  Just like any other variable, it's desirable for constants to have the minimum visibility necessary.  Having a private constant implies that it isn't used in the rest of the program... in which case why does the rest of the program even need to be told that it exists?

Answer (score 0):

I Just want to start with this is probably a bad idea, but this is how you do static stuff in c++:

```
//A.h
class A
{
private:
    static inline const char* Ptr();
    class static_A
    {
    private:
        char* m_ptr;
        char* AllocateAndReadFile();//SUPER UNSAFE AND BAD CODE (Make sure it is SUPER hidden from end users, put warning comments all over the place
    public:
        static_A();
        ~static_A();
        friend const char* A::Ptr(void);
    };
    static static_A a_init;


public:
    A();
};
//i'd probably put this indirection function here, in definition so its inlined
inline const char* A::Ptr()
{
    return a_init.m_ptr;
}

//A.cpp
A::static_A A::a_init = A::static_A();

A::static_A::static_A() : m_ptr(AllocateAndReadFile())
{
}
A::static_A::~static_A()
{
    delete [] m_ptr;
}
char* A::static_A::AllocateAndReadFile()
{
    char* foo = new char[1000000];
    memset(foo,0,sizeof(char)*1000000);
    //put your read function here...note that because read must be static, 
    //the file location must be hard coded, so I don't like this solution at all
    FILE* fid = fopen("C:/stuff.txt","r");
    size_t readchars = fread(foo,sizeof(char),1000000,fid);
    return foo;
}

A::A()
{
    char buff[100];
    memcpy(buff,Ptr(),99);
    printf(buff);
}
```

You could also make a_init an opaque pointer and put the entire definition of A::static_A in `A.cpp`...that might be better in this case.

Answer (score -3):

It is impossible.

`const` keywords means set value at compile time, but you want to read from file which is a runtime operation, so it is impossible.

Define `bar` as static bot not const, be careful to don't change it.

Comment: You can usually cast to const: **`const` does NOT mean set at compile time** but rather that the value pointed to by the variable cannot be changed within this context. This is why you can have const arguments to functions.