# A const big array needs to be initialized

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization

I have a static array of `double`s inside my class, and I would like it to be `const`, but I need to initialize it somehow. What is the best way of ensuring that it will be "`const`" after the constructor returns?

```
class DFTDriver {        
public:
    static const size_t tblsize = 16384;
    DFTDriver() {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != tblsize; ++i) {
            sintbl[i] = std::sin(i * TAU / tblsize);
            costbl[i] = std::cos(i * TAU / tblsize);
        }
    }
private:
    static double sintbl[tblsize];
    static double costbl[tblsize];
};
```

I know I need a computation to initialize them, so it wouldn't be reasonable to ask them to be `const`; however, the array is clearly "semantically `const`".

I see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113551/c-const-static-member-array-initialization) there is an answer if I am initializing a vector instead of an array. Is it possible to use a similar approach?

I would like to be able to do it without appealing to new C++11 constructs, but if it's not possible, then let C++11 do it.

Comment: If it's static... why are you initializing it in the constructor (i.e a non-static function)

Comment: You can use an initializer list just like any other array in the definition. You'd have to compute the values, though.

Comment: That's right, I should be initializing it in the main() function, or something like this. Any way, my question remains, how to make them "const" after the "initializion" (which looks like an assingnment, but should be an initialization) ?

Comment: You don't make it const after initialization. You declare it const which means your only chance of deciding its values is at initialization. And btw, main is the wrong place to do that. P.S: I would suggest you use vector and follow the technique in the question you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that a lot of people here would love to vote down my answer, nevertheless I hope they will think a bit before doing so.

Maybe this problem is exactly the case when simple casting should be used. The data field should be declared const. This will guarantee that it will not be accidentally changed somewhere. You should allocate non const pointer in your initialization function and point it to your data. Do casting, add detailed comment with explanation why you are doing this and you will be fine. Pros:

1. The code will be absolutely clear;
2. It will run without trouble on any platform/compiler;
3. Casting will be just in one place that is not likely to be changed.

p.s. I would recommend adding static instance of your class and making your ctor private. This will guarantee that the ctor will be called in the very beginning:

```
class DFTDriver
{        
private:

    DFTDriver() { .... }

    static DTFDriver inst;

    static double sintbl[tblsize];
    static double costbl[tblsize];
};
```

The other answer with generated source also makes sense although the code will be more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Make a program to generate the tables

```
FILE * file = fopen( "sintbl.cpp", "w" );
fprintf( file, "const double DFTDriver::sintbl[] = {\n" );
for (unsigned i = 0; i != tblsize; ++i) {
    fprint( file, "  %f , \n", std::sin(i * TAU / tblsize) );
}
fprintf( file, "};\n" );
fclose( file );
```

And then compile the generated file and link it into your program.

Comment: .. and you can run this generator program within your build system. An example for CMake: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html#s5

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
class DFTDriver {   
    template<class ElementType, size_t size>
    struct Buffer
    {
        Buffer(ElementType(*initializer)(size_t i)) {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                data[i] = initializer(i);
            }
        }
        const ElementType operator[](size_t i) const {return data[i];}
        ElementType& operator[](size_t i) {return data[i];}
        ElementType data[size];
    };
    double initSinbl(size_t i) { 
         return std::sin(i * TAU / tblsize);
    }
    double initCosbl(size_t i) {
        return std::cos(i * TAU / tblsize);
    }
public:
    static const size_t tblsize = 16384;
private:
    //initSinbl and initCosbl can be replaced with lambdas in c++11
    static const Buffer<double, tblsize> sintbl(&initSinbl);
    static const Buffer<double, tblsize> costbl(&initCosbl);
};
```